# Select for Update Lock

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, select-for-update

I want to prevent simultaneous update(by multiple sessions) for my record in my stored procedure.

1.I am , using SELECT FOR UPDATE statement for the particular row , which i want to update it.
This will lock the record.

1. I am updating this record now and then commit it. So the lock is released and now the record is available for another user/session to work on with.

However , when i try to run the procedure , i am finding the simultaneous update is happening , means SELECT FOR UPDATE not working fine.

Pls provide some suggestions.

Sample Code is below :

```
IF THEN
// do something
ELSIF THEN
BEGIN

 SELECT HIGH_NBR INTO P_NBR FROM ROUTE
 WHERE LC_CD = <KL_LCD> AND ROUTE_NBR =  <KL_ROUTE_NBR> 
 FOR UPDATE OF HIGH_NBR ;

 UPDATE ROUTE SET HIGH_NBR = (HIGH_NBR + 1) 
 WHERE LC_CD = <KL_LCD> AND ROUTE_NBR =  <KL_ROUTE_NBR>;

COMMIT;

END;

END IF;
```

In multiple user environment , i am observing the SELECT FOR UPDATE lock is not happening.

I just tested the scenario with two different computers (Sessions). Here is what i have did.

1. From One computer , executed SELECT FOR UPDATE statement -- Locking a row.
2. From Another computer , execute an UPDATE statement for the same record.
3. Update did not happen and the Sql execution of update statement is not completed , even after a long time.

   When will be the lock released , if we issue an SELECT FOR UPDATE for a record.

Comment: Please show a more complete set of the code.

Comment: Updated the Code Snippet.

Comment: How did you run the procedure 2x in parallel?  In a debugger?

Comment: @OldProgrammer No .. I deployed the code in our DEV environment. Please let me know , if there is a way to run the procedure in parallel. I am usin Sql Developer , for writing my queries .

Comment: So step through the pl/sql code in the sql developer debugger.  I guarantee that if you set a breakpoint after the select, and then call the procedure from another session (say, sqlplus) it should block.  You can also query the v$lock view to see the locking in action. [Here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/854) is a good link.

Comment: For a debugging "aid" add long enough [`dbms_lock.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_lock.htm) call between the `select` and `update` statements. Now you should be able to observe the blocking behaviour easily with multiple sessions.

Comment: How long is this lock being held?

Comment: @BobJarvis Updated my test scenario is main post.

Comment: The lock will be released when the transaction is committed, after which the blocked UPDATE will be allowed to proceed.  This may not be what you had in mind, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to set auto commit false before starting the query.
and to check your code is working you can use two Java treads with a cyclic barrier 
and also you should add timestamps on you code to check the time of the code being reached.